# Visual Studio - How to run the executable generated?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Having compiled the release version executable file from the project, how can I run the project outside of visual studio ?
I tried to double-click the exe or run it in a command-line but doesn't work. The project contains some external files, including pictures.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: You need to provide more information on the error you're getting than "It doesn't work"

Comment: what kind of project is it?

Comment: If nothing happens after you click the EXE, check task manager to see whats going on with it in the processes tab.

Comment: Try debugging it, check the actual dependencies (depends.exe), put diagnostic messages, etc. to figure where the problem could be. There might be a million reasons it doesn't work, how could we know?

Comment: Too general a question.

Comment: Please provide few more details, like what were you expecting to see while running from command line or by clicking the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the executable byside the files you have referenced in your Project.

If your executable is in a seperate Folder, you have to set in your Project under references each referenced .dll to copy local true.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am looking for [Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).